# Google Sheets, how to count if text is set column is set to true

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheets with the following layout

```
Key Points  Category    Done
1     4       A          Yes
2     4       B 
3     1       B 
4     5       C          Yes
5     7       D          Yes
6     4       B 
7     2       C          Yes
```

I need a formula that can sum the points based on category if the Done is "yes". So the output should be

```
Points done    Category
7                C
4                A
7                D
```

Whch formula can I use for this? (I don't want to use pivot table)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:D}; "select sum(Col2),Col3 where Col4 = 'Yes' group by Col3 label sum(Col2)''")
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: Col3

Comment: I believe that it might need the "group by" clause to allow the sum(Col2) to work.  Try:  =QUERY({A2:D}; "select sum(Col2),Col3 where Col4 = 'Yes' group by Col3 label sum(Col2)''")                                                                                                                                     You can also change the order they appear, by using "order by Col3", if you want the output sorted by category, or "order by sum(Col2)" if you want to sort by points.